# Ordenar DataTables rango fecha

Tags: jquery, datatables

Tengo dos inputs (fecha minima y fecha maxima) con los cuales quiero filtrar los resultados de mis tablas, el problema es que **DataTables** tiene un problema serio con la ordenación de fechas. He leído por internet que para los que quieren tener el formato dd/mm/YYYY hay un poco de rollo y recomiendan hacer un "truquillo" que es más rápido que otra opción pero solo funciona en el campo de búsqueda que trae por defecto DataTables, pero con dos inputs no funciona.

Este "truquillo" consiste en meter un  con display none con la fecha en formato YYYYMMDD de este modo el usuario no ve el contenido del  pero DataTables si puede realizar la ordenación.

```
<td><span style='display: none;'>20150221</span>21/02/2015</td>
```

Hasta aquí bien con el filtrado del buscador por defecto de DataTables, la cosa es que quisiera dos inputs y poner un intervalo de fechas. Y con el siguiente código no me funciona, empieza filtrando bien pero cuando acabo de escribir la fecha máxima ya no filtra correctamente.

La cosa es que no sé si el primer "truquillo" afecta al segundo caso o viceversa, alguien que haya tenido el mismo problema o similar sabría iluminarme un poco? Aquí dejo mi código.

```
    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
      function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        var iFini = document.getElementById('min').value;
        var iFfin = document.getElementById('max').value;
        var iStartDateCol = 4;
        var iEndDateCol = 4;

        iFini = iFini.substring(6,10) + iFini.substring(3,5) + iFini.substring(0,2);
        iFfin = iFfin.substring(6,10) + iFfin.substring(3,5) + iFfin.substring(0,2);

        var datofini=aData[iStartDateCol].substring(6,10) + aData[iStartDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iStartDateCol].substring(0,2);
        var datoffin=aData[iEndDateCol].substring(6,10) + aData[iEndDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iEndDateCol].substring(0,2);

        if (iFini === "" && iFfin === "") {
          return true;
        } else if (iFini <= datofini && iFfin === "") {
          return true;
        } else if (iFfin >= datoffin && iFini === "") {
          return true;
        } else if (iFini <= datofini && iFfin >= datoffin) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    );

    var table_filter = $('#DataTables_Table_4').dataTable();

    $('#min').keyup( function() { table_filter.fnDraw(); } );
    $('#max').keyup( function() { table_filter.fnDraw(); } );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final después de intentar de todo, he probado la librería **moment.js** y he modificado la función de filtrado para que admita el formato **dd-mm-YYYY**

http://momentjs.com/

dejo aquí el código:

```
    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
            function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
                var filterstart = $('#min').val();
                var filterend = $('#max').val();
                var iStartDateCol = 4;
                var iEndDateCol = 4;

                var tabledatestart = aData[iStartDateCol];
                var tabledateend = aData[iEndDateCol];

                var minDay = filterstart.substring(0,2);
                var minMonth = filterstart.substring(3,5);
                var minYear = filterstart.substring(6,10);

                var maxDay = filterend.substring(0,2);
                var maxMonth = filterend.substring(3,5);
                var maxYear = filterend.substring(6,10);

                filterstart = minYear + minMonth + minDay;
                filterend = maxYear + maxMonth + maxDay;

                if ( filterstart === "" && filterend === "" )
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if ((moment(filterstart).isSame(tabledatestart) || moment(filterstart).isBefore(tabledatestart)) && filterend === "")
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if ((moment(filterstart).isSame(tabledatestart) || moment(filterstart).isAfter(tabledatestart)) && filterstart === "")
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if ((moment(filterstart).isSame(tabledatestart) || moment(filterstart).isBefore(tabledatestart)) && (moment(filterend).isSame(tabledateend) || moment(filterend).isAfter(tabledateend)))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
    );
```

No hace falta quitar el "truquillo" para que funcione.